# Admob OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, webview, admob, out-of-memory

I am using Google Admob ads in my application, but i have got a lot of crash reports indicating OutOfMemoryError in admob,

Here is the full crash stack trace,

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:359)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:715)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1721)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:585)
at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:1079)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1903)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1945)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:320)
at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:997)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:980)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:970)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:961)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a.<init>(SourceFile:136)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a.a(SourceFile:124)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.b.a(SourceFile:484)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.e.run(SourceFile:191)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am defining ads in the xml files,

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ID" />
```

Please could you help in resolving this error ?

Regards

Comment: show some of your code where you defining admob

Comment: @raj question updated

Comment: This issue might be caused by parts of your application which uses too much memory. Do you see this exception always or just on some devices?

Comment: @user714965 The exception is reported from different devices and different android versions

Answer (score -1):

you can use my code which is working perfectly i am using table to show add in xml

This is my adview using google play services wroking perfactly

```
TableRow TR = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.TR);
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(getString("your admob id here"));
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
TR.addView(adView);

adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

xml code

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/TR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Manifest file

```
<activity
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="5089000" />
```

Comment: I am doing something like this, why you use table row to ad the adview ?

Comment: bcoz i was unable to load ads in xml layout using google play services

Comment: You can load ads in XML, refer to admob samples attached with Google play service lib

Comment: i have only given an alternate method